# Match one string with other which is fetched from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, compare, match

we are trying to match one string with another (i.e. more than one string) which is fetch from mysql database.

```
<?php
$verdeel = explode(" ",strtolower('sony xperia c3 black'));

$getallen =explode(" ",strtolower('Sony Xperia c3 dual sim'));

if(array_intersect($verdeel, $getallen))
{

for($i=0;$i < count($verdeel);$i++){

    if($verdeel[$i] == $getallen[$i]){
        echo $getallen[$i];
    } else {
        echo "no match";    
    }
  }
}
?>
```

In the above example we matches "sony xperia c3 black" which is input string matches  with the second string "Sony Xperia c3 dual sim".
The second string may be more than one
e.g. "Sony Xperia c3 dual sim",
"Sony Xperia c3 dual sim black 1GB ram",
"Sony Xperia c3 black 1GB ram"....etc.

In above code if we found any match keyword then the output is that keyword.
Upto this point we are correct, But instead of giving match keyword we require the whole string which is fetched from database(one or more) that have Found MAXIMUM MATCHED KEYWORD STRINGs (i.e. list of product name with maximum matched keyword is in top like in descending order to compare product is our main porpose)....
is it right way to compare product when we select one product name from database.Or u have different idea to compare prices of product.
Plz suggest me the right way.
Thanks for your co-operation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%sony%'
or LOWER(title) LIKE '%xperia%'
or LOWER(title) LIKE '%black%'
```

In this way you just retrieve records from database which they have any similarity to "sony xperia c3 black"

you can make query like this in PHP programmatically:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE ';
$keywords = explode(" ",strtolower('sony xperia c3 black'));
foreach($keywords as $key => $keyword){
    if($key == 0)
        $query .='LOWER(title) LIKE %'.$keyword.'%';
    else
        $query .='or LOWER(title) LIKE %'.$keyword.'%';
}
```

Now suppose we run the query and we have similar products' titles in an array and we want to sort them.
We can achieve it like this:

```
//$titles is an array containing similar products title
//$keywords is the array we made above by exploding input string
foreach($titles as $key => $title){
   $title = strtolower($title);
   $title = explode(' ',$title);
   $matched[$key] = sizeof(array_intersect($keywords,$title));
}
array_multisort($matched, $titles);
```

after this values in $titles are sorted according to their similarity with input string

[array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

[array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: Thanks for your support......I hope above query gives me proper output, but in this case after database connection when i fetch record by using-    $final=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($final));
{
 print_r($row);
}       In this case it gives me error :-Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\word\custom-look\try1.php      In $query->our above query